# How do you convert a hex to signed float in Swift? Works fine with positive number but doesn't work on negative

Tags: swift, floating-point, hex, int32

```
let hexString = "0x42f9b6c9"
let toInt = Int32(truncatingBitPattern: strtoul(self, nil, 16))
let toFloat = Float(bitPattern: UInt32(self))
```

RESULT: 124.857

```
let hexString = "0xc2f9b6c9"
let toInt = Int32(truncatingBitPattern: strtoul(self, nil, 16))
let toFloat = Float(bitPattern: UInt32(self))
```

app crashes here because the value is negative, expected result is -124.857

Please help. Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

`strtoul` means string to unsigned long.  Try `strtol`

Comment: Also, the "U" in UInt32 stands for "unsigned".

Comment: @creeperspeak, really? Sincerely, I always thought it meant Unicode. Learn something new every day. Thanks! (And yeah, now that I'm actually thinking, what's the difference between an Int that's Unicode or not. In fact, what *would* a unicode Int mean?)

Comment: Thank you :) But do you guys know how to convert it to signed?

Comment: @user You'll also need to say `UInt32(truncatingBitPattern: ...` instead of using `Int32`.

Answer (score 0):

Better to make an extension of String

```
extension String {
func hexToFloat() -> Float {
    var toInt = Int32(truncatingBitPattern: strtol(self, nil, 16))
    var float:Float32!
    memcpy(&float, &toInt, MemoryLayout.size(ofValue: float))
    print("\(float)")
    return float
}
```

}

Example

```
"0xc2f9b6c9".hexToFloat()
//-124.857
"0x41240000".hexToFloat()
//10.25
```